# Android app monthly charging

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I want to make an android app and the employer wants me to make this application to have a login mechanism. There will be a monthly charge for each user(let's say 2 $/month).First 3 days of use will be free.

Please tell me a way to do this. Should I use in-app billing? Or android market has something similar?

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: You need to check the legal agreement with your market service to see what out-of-app billing is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a server at your disposal (for login checks), so you could just have users pay for the account (which could be done both on the phone and online).

The login-server could then check if the account has paid or is in trial status

Comment: I do have a server, but I don't know how to perform the payment via phone(gather informations entered by user about credit card and sent them where??)

Comment: Paypal might be on of the best options.  They can do subscriptions as well, so you could just check with them if a user has paid